# I want to make my header left as well as right aligned

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop, winforms-interop

I am trying to put some image in header of Word document through Microsoft. Office.Interop.Word.
I want to place the picture stretched to both boundaries of document but I am unable to do so; whenever I set right and left indent it only changes the left indent like image is only stretched on the left side but not on the right side, Any type of help will be very precious to me. This is the snippet I am trying with:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section wordSection in docWord.Sections)
{
    wordSection.PageSetup.HeaderDistance = 0;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    //footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkRed;
    //footerRange.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = -(docWord.Application.CentimetersToPoints(3));
    footerRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\\test\\footer.png");

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerRange = wordSection.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    //headerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkRed;
    MessageBox.Show((headerRange.ParagraphFormat.RightIndent - (docWord.Application.CentimetersToPoints(72))).ToString());
    //headerRange.ParagraphFormat.RightIndent = (docWord.Application.InchesToPoints(-1));
    //headerRange.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = -(docWord.Application.CentimetersToPoints(3));
    headerRange.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = -(docWord.Application.CentimetersToPoints(3));
    //MessageBox.Show(headerRange.ParagraphFormat.RightIndent.ToString());
    //headerRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore =0 ;
    headerRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\\test\\header.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked with Microsoft.interope Library. You are doing it correctly. Unfortunately, Microsoft.interope does not provide support for stretch header.

Comment: Abdul Thanks for your answer. I got it after trying some hard.